# Help with an exam question on the adjoinment of $\alpha \in GF(17)$ to $GF(17)$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I've been looking over past exam papers and I came across a question I could not solve , it says ;

Consider $F:=GF(17^4),$

i)if $\alpha\in F$ what are the possible orders of $\Bbb Z_{17}(\alpha)$

ii) If $\alpha \in F$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^4-5$ over $\Bbb Z_{17}$ what are the other 3 roots.

I'm really not sure how to approach the question though . I have soe inklings but I don't know if they will prove fruitful or not, my thughts are ;

i) if $\alpha \in F$ , then the order of the element should divide the order of the group $F^*$. So the possible orders of $\alpha$ are 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10 etc.... but it seems like there are two many possible orders. So the second thing I think is that perhaps because $\Bbb Z_{17}$ has order 17 and F has order $17^4$, that theres some way to calculate this using GF(17) instead ?

ii)check all elements of $GF(17^4)$ but again there are far oo many to do this

Could anyone please help ?

Comment: This question contains the method on how to do ii)
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788599/roots-of-x8-3-over-gf17

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf F_{17^4}$, as a vector space over $\mathbf F_{17}$ has degree $4$, and $\mathbf F_{17}(\alpha)$ has degree a divisor of $4$. So its order can be $17$, $17^2$ or $17^4$.

Hint for ii): What are the fourth roots of $1$ in  $\mathbf F_{17}$?

Comment: If I understand you correctly the 4th roots are the elements of $GF(17)$ which generate 1 when taken to the 4th power ? In which case I believe they are 1, 4, 9, 16 ? So then does that mean the possible orders of $ GF(17)(\alpha)$ are 1,4,16,9 ? I'm not really sure I see why

Comment: Yes, the elements are correct (I prefer to write them as $\pm 1,\,\pm 4$.  No, the possible orders are not those. What is  $\mathbf F_{17}(\alpha)$ w.r.t.  $\mathbf F_{17}$?

Comment: Unless you don't mean by order the number of elements?

Comment: well I would have thought that $F_{17}(\alpha:=\{a+b\alpha +c\alpha^2+.......|abc,.... \in F(17)\}$ but I don't know how to figure out the order of $alpha$ so I don't think I can use this method ?

Comment: But they don't ask the order of $\alpha$ (what does that mean, anyway?), they ask for the order of the field $\mathbf F_{17}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Oh my gosh ,  sorry for invalidating the helpful answers you've already given but i just realised that i made a typo when typing the question . It was meant to read $\alpha \in GF(17^4)$....

Comment: does that then mean that the order is 1, 2, 3 or 4 ? as if $\alpha \in GF(17^4)$ then $\alpha \in GF(17),GF(17^2),GF(17^3),GF(17^4)$ ?

Comment: No, not any exponent can be used for the order. Please see my updated answer.